# Custom TabView: How to avoid the use of AnyView?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview

I wanted to create a custom `TabView` the same way Apple did. I think most of it is done but I cannot manage to get rid of the use of AnyView in my ViewModifer `tabItem` to allow the tabs to contain different kind of views. If I get rid of the `AnyView` I get some build issues saying :

> Cannot convert value of type 'TabItem<Int, Image>' to expected argument type 'TabItem<Int, Text>'

Here is how I want my view to be used:

```swift
struct TabContainer_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        PreviewWrapper {
            StateWrapper(0) { selectedTab in
                TabView(selection: selectedTab) {
                    Text("first tab")
                        .tabItem(tag: 0, for: "Text1")
                    
                    Image(.account)
                        .tabItem(tag: 1, for: "Text2")
                    
                    Text("third tab")
                        .tabItem(tag: 2, for: "Text3")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the AnyView I want to get rid of :

```swift
public extension View {
    func tabItem<SelectionValue>(tag: SelectionValue, for label: String) -> TabItem<SelectionValue, AnyView> where SelectionValue: Hashable {
        return TabItem(tag: tag, label: label) {
            AnyView(self)
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the rest of the code :

```
import SwiftUI

public struct TabView<SelectionValue, Content>: View where SelectionValue: Hashable, Content: View {
    
    @Binding var selection: SelectionValue
    let content: [TabItem<SelectionValue, Content>]
    
    /// Creates a TabView
    /// - Parameters:
    ///   - selection: A binding to the value representing the tab selected
    ///   - content: The views contained inside the tabs. The tabItem modifier has to be applied to each view. 
    public init(selection: Binding<SelectionValue>,
         @TabViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> [TabItem<SelectionValue, Content>]) {
        self._selection = selection
        self.content = content()
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: .zero) {
            HStack(spacing: .zero) {
                ForEach(content, id: \.tag) { item in
                    Tab(label: item.label, isSelected: item.tag == selection)
                        .onTapGesture {
                            withAnimation {
                                selection = item.tag
                            }
                        }
                }
            }
            
            SwiftUI.TabView(selection: $selection) {
                ForEach(content, id: \.tag) { tabItem in
                    tabItem
                        .tag(tabItem.tag)
                }
            }
            .tabViewStyle(.page(indexDisplayMode: .never))
        }
    }
}

@resultBuilder
public struct TabViewBuilder {
    public static func buildBlock<SelectionValue,Content>(_ components: TabItem<SelectionValue, Content>...) -> [TabItem<SelectionValue, Content>] where SelectionValue: Hashable, Content: View {
        return components
    }
    public static func buildEither<SelectionValue,Content>(first component: TabItem<SelectionValue, Content>) -> TabItem<SelectionValue, Content> where SelectionValue: Hashable, Content: View {
        return component
    }
    public static func buildEither<SelectionValue,Content>(second component: TabItem<SelectionValue, Content>) -> TabItem<SelectionValue, Content> where SelectionValue: Hashable, Content: View {
        return component
    }
}

public struct TabItem<SelectionValue, Content>: View where SelectionValue: Hashable, Content: View {
    
    let tag: SelectionValue
    let label: String
    @ViewBuilder let content: () -> Content
    
    public init(tag: SelectionValue, label: String, @ViewBuilder content: @escaping () -> Content) {
        self.tag = tag
        self.label = label
        self.content = content
    }
    
    public var body: some View {
        content()
    }
}

struct Tab: View {
    
    let label: String
    let isSelected: Bool
    
    init(label: String, isSelected: Bool) {
        self.label = label
        self.isSelected = isSelected
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        Text(label)
            .foregroundColor(isSelected ? .primaryDefault : .textSecondary)
            .lineLimit(1)
            .padding(.vertical, .small)
            .padding(.horizontal, .medium)
            .frame(maxWidth: .infinity)
            .background(Color.surfaceLow)
            .overlay {
                VStack {
                    Spacer()
                    color.frame(height: 2)
                }
            }
    }
    
    var color: Color {
        return isSelected ? .primaryDefault : .outlineDefault
    }
}
```

I would greatly appreciate some help on this!

EDIT: I would like to init my view the same way as Apple's TabView. I would like this kind of init possible but with my custom layout:

```swift
TabView(selection: $selection) {
    Text("first tab")
        .tag(0)
    
    Image(.imagePlaceholder)
        .tag(1)
    
    Text("second tab")
        .tag(2)
}
```

Comment: `I wanted to create a custom TabView the same way Apple did.` can you add a screenshot for it... Apple have many things...

Comment: @FahimParkar I would like my view to behave the same as Apple's TabView. For example this is possible with Apple's TabView. In my case I have to use AnyView(self) in my TabView modifier to make it work. But it is not great.

`
TabView(selection: $selection) {
                Text("first tab")
                    .tag(0)
                
                Image(.imagePlaceholder)
                    .tag(1)
                
                Text("second tab")
                    .tag(2)
            }
`

Comment: Views don't belong in Arrays, you have to break up each component

Comment: I understand that it is not common. But how is Apple handling this kind of ViewBuilder then ? I just want to replicate the same kind of init as Apple's TabView.

Comment: Apple doesn’t deal with Views themselves they have access to lower level code. Look at SwiftUI.Layout.

Comment: @loremipsum So there is no way to do it without accessing some lower level code ? Which can be rejected at the review. The proper way would be to implement entirely the TabView again and use preferenceKey to get back the tag of each view and display everything in a ZStack. But preferenceKey only works if the view is in the hierarchy, so every tab would be in the hierarchy at all time. Do you think it might do the trick because I fear it wouldn't be great on the performance side ? Or maybe you have another idea ?

Comment: I don’t think so. Why not just use UIKit? SwiftUI is meant for rapid production and maximum compatibility. At the expense of customizations.

Comment: Our entire project is in SwiftUI. It would be great if we could avoid the use of UIKit and keep some consistency in the use of our views.

Comment: Maybe in June? Layout came out last year maybe we’ll get something else. The whole point of ViewBuilder is to mask the insides of a View and turn it into one indistinguishable unit.

Comment: Actually I found a post which was entirely describing what I wanted to do. Here it is : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75320164/swiftui-custom-tabview-with-paging-style. I tried the answer from @Timmy. It seems that for him it was possible to use some generics but didn't want to do it in this post. Unfortunately I don't have enough reputation to ask him directly how he would do it.

Comment: That post is at the same spot as you are right in between ViewBuilder and AnyView. They will run into the same issues as you are but since you tagged the author maybe they can come up with a solution.